# Erro ORA-00942 TABLE DOES NOT EXIST ocorrendo em System.Data.OracleClient. VB.NET

Tags: .net, oracle, vb.net

Tenho uma aplicação em [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) usando *.Net Framework 2.0*.

Abaixo segue um trecho do código da minha aplicação:

```
strComando = "SELECT CD_LOCALIDADE, NO_LOCALIDADE FROM COPAGIS_GDB.MUB_LOCALIDADES WHERE FL_IMPLANTADO='S' ORDER BY NO_LOCALIDADE"
fsOarquivo.WriteLine(strComando)
pComando = _controleAcessoDados.ProxyBD.MontarComando(strComando)
fsOarquivo.WriteLine(pComando.CommandText)
dataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(pComando)
fsOarquivo.WriteLine(dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText)
dataAdapter.Fill(tblTabelas)
fsOarquivo.WriteLine(tblTabelas)
```

A execução desse trecho do código produz o erro

```
ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist
```

no comando

```
dataAdapter.Fill(tblTabelas)
```

Utilizei o sqlnet para gerar um trace para mostrar o que o cliente oracle está recebendo da aplicação. Segue o trecho do trace abaixo.

[image: imagem do trace do sqlnet]

Observem na imagem do trace do sqlnet em anexo que o código SQL está modificado no trace file. Foi incluído o número '5' no nome da tabela.

Alguém sabe me dizer por que isso está acontecendo? Estou usando `System.Data.OracleClient` da Microsoft.

Comment: Faça duas verificações: Primeiro Existe realmente a Tabela?
Segundo, verifica o pComando se a string não foi alterada antes de entrar no OracleDataAdapter... Não creio que seja o Adapter que esteja mudando a sua query... pode ser provável que o MontarComando esteja fazendo isso, mas só verifica pra ter certeza

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Já fiz essa conferência. Eu anexei uma imagem do arquivo de trace produzida pelo SQLNET onde mostra o comando SQL modificado.

Comment: Um outro fato interessante relativo a esse problema. Seu executo a aplicação de dentro do visual studio funciona sem erro. Seu executo fora do visual studio o erro ocorre.

Comment: Você está executando fora do vs na mesma máquina e ambiente, ou máquina/ambientes diferentes?

Comment: Na mesma máquina.

Answer (score 1):

Veja também se o usuário que logou no BD é o do OWNER da tabela, não sendo e não querendo alterar altere o select para algo do tipo

```
select * from owner.tabela
```

Veja também se o usuário do login tem o GRANT de slect desta tabela/view.

Comment: O usuário que logou é o owner, consequentemente tem o grant.